# Dart required value in class without curly braces

Tags: flutter, dart

Using curly braces in a class I can use the `@required` parameter and this way I can have one value that is required, and one optional, as follows:

```
class MyClass extends StatelessWidget {
    MyClass({@required this.colour, this.other});

    final Color colour;
    final Widget other;

  }
```

But that means I have to call it like this:

```
MyClass(colour: Color(0xFF1D1E33))
```

Whereas I'd rather call it like this:

```
MyClass(Color(0xFF1D1E00))
```

If I remove the curly braces I can do this, but I found I cannot have a required an optional value this way:

```
  class MyClass extends StatelessWidget {
    MyClass(@required this.colour, this.other);

    final Color colour;
    final Widget other;

  }
```

It throws an error. How can I make a value optional without curly braces?

Comment: `MyClass(this.color, [this.other]);`

Comment: @pskink So if I don't use `[]` then the value is automatically required? Whereas with this method `MyClass({this.colour, this.other});` neither value is explicitly required *unless* I use the `@required` parameter?

Comment: Yes, have you read "dart language tour"?

Comment: @pskink No, I'll take a look at it. I was going through a video tutorial and it mentioned the first way but not the second so I was curious. It seems strange that with one way you have to mark the required parameter (@required), and with the other way you have to mark the optional parameter with `[]`...

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use positional argument denoted by `[]`

```
MyClass extends StatelessWidget {
  MyClass(this.colour, [this.other]);

  final Color colour;
  final Widget other;

}
```

So, in order to instantiate the class you need to use

```
MyClass(Color(0xFF1D1E00)); // in this case other will be null

MyClass(Color(0xFF1D1E00), Container()); // other will be Container
```

Comment: So if I don't use [] then the value is automatically required? Whereas with this method MyClass({this.colour, this.other}); neither value is explicitly required unless I use the @required parameter?

Comment: @Hasen The point of `[]` and `{}` for parameters is to make them optional.  Non-optional means required.

Comment: @jamesdlin I think you mean `@required` makes them required. So to make two parameters optional it would be like this `MyClass(this.color, [this.other, this.andanother]);` or like this `MyClass(this.color, [this.other], [this.andanother]);`

Comment: @Hasen what he meant was if you don't use `[]` or `{}`, the parameter becomes required without you having to write `@required`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I know the first part of this comment was saying to use [] and {} parameters to make them optional. I was correcting the second part of this comment  'non-optional means required' which seemed rather a stupid thing to say and must have been a mistake. Unless he's lost and looking for the english.stackexchange.com website.